# SP_executeSQL error - Errors When Combining Statements

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, execute

I have written this cursor

```
DECLARE IMGPATH CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    select ImageFileName from tempImageFiles
OPEN IMGPATH

FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @ImageFileName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
    --SELECT @ImageFileName = LEFT(@ImageFileName, (6-4))
        SET @strSQLtoExecute = N'INSERT tempImage (imageData) SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''C:\Temp\Images\' + @ImageFileName + ''', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS x'
        PRINT @strSQLtoExecute 
        EXEC SP_executeSQL @strSQLtoExecute, @ImageFileName

FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @ImageFileName
 END

CLOSE IMGPATH
DEALLOCATE IMGPATH
```

on execution I get the following error

```
INSERT tempImage (imageData) 
    SELECT BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Images\1.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS x
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '1.'.

```
INSERT tempImage (imageData) 
    SELECT BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Images\10.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS x
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '10.'.

```
INSERT tempImage (imageData) 
    SELECT BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Images\11.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS x
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '11.'.

But if I execute each statement individually it works fine.

Confused now.

Comment: It looks like it is upset by backslash number in the path.  Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters statement should look like:

```
EXEC SP_executeSQL @strSQLtoExecute, @ImageFileName=@ImageFileName
```

I think this will fix your problem.

Or, leave out the parameter entirely, and change the execute string:

```
    SET @strSQLtoExecute = N'INSERT tempImage (imageData) SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''C:\Temp\Images\'' + @ImageFileName + '''', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS x'
```